# Creating Android OpenCV project on Eclipse without OpenCv Package Manager

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, opencv

I am looking for an example OpenCv Android project on eclipse. All the tutorials that I have seen so far: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-static-initialization

Point to using OpenCV package manager. How do I setup a project with OpenCV Library (Java and Native) without using the Package Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the problem by adding the following to my Android.mk:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=STATIC 
include ../thirdparty/opencv-android-sdk/sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

Then by including opencv_java3 library:

```
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    // Handle initialization error
    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCVLoader Failed");
} else {
    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCVLoader Succeeded");

    Log.i(TAG, "Loading opencv_java3...");
    java.lang.System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
    Log.i(TAG, "Finished Loading opencv_java3...");
}
```